# after uploading multiple images need to put thay names in my db

Tags: php, mysqli

I successfully uploaded my images using php and looping but the problem with me is how put the names of the uploaded files into my db

and this is my code .

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Add event</title>
<link href="../css_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

    <?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include_once "../config/config.php";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $target = 'upload_occasion/';

        $title = $_POST['img_title'];
        $des = $_POST['img_des'];
        $putData = " insert into photos_occasion (id, title, description) values ('', '$title', '$des' ) ";
        $result = $db->query($putData) or die ($db->error);


        foreach ($_FILES["img"]["error"] as $key => $error) 
{
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
    {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["img"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$target/$name");

        $putData = " insert into photos_occasion ( id, image_name ) values ( '', '$target/$name' ) ";
        $result = $db->query($putData);
    }
}

    if ($result) {

                echo "Your event has been add successfully";

                }else{

                    echo "Sorry there was an error please contact the administrator of the site"; 

                    }
        }

     ?>

<body>
<div id="werpper">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="header">My control - Panel</div>
                <div id="body_cntent">
                    <div id="left_side">
                      <p>Home and instructions</p>
                          <p><a href="../control_panel.php">main directory events</a></p>
                      <p>Active or unactive events</p>
                      <p><a href="includes/add_event.php">Add new event</a></p>
                      <p><a href="../control_panel.php">main directory photos</a></p>
                      <p>Add Photos </p>
                    </div>
                            <div id="right_side">

                                <h1>Add  Photos and occasion</h1>
                             <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                               <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="10">
                                 <tr>
                                   <td>Images tiltle</td>
                                   <td><input name="img_title" type="text" value="" size="50" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td>Images Description</td>
                                   <td><textarea name="img_des" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td>Images (max 10 img)</td>
                                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img1">Image 1</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img2">Image 2</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField2" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img3">Image 3</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField3" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img4">Image 4</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField4" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img5">Image 5</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField5" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img6">Image 6</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField6" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img7">Image 7</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField7" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img8">Image 8</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField8" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img9">Image 9</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField9" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img10">Image 10</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField10" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                   <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
                                     &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                   <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Empty fields" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>
                             </form>
                        </div>
                </div>
             <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

1- I can't put they names in my db so I can get them after afterwards(still)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem 1 :
you probably want $title, not $img_title ( and look at problem 2 )

try this :

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
include_once( "../config/config.php" );

if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) )
{
    $target = 'upload_occasion/';

    $title = $_POST[ 'img_title' ];
    $des = $_POST[ 'img_des' ];

    // insert occasion info
    $putData = "INSERT INTO photos_occasion ( id, title, description ) values ( '', '$title', '$des' )";
    $result = $db->query( $putData ) or die ( $db->error );

    // NOTICE THIS LINE .. you should implement something to get the inserted id (maybe from the $result)
    $photoOccasionID = GET_INSERTED_ID_SOMEHOW;

    // then update occasion with each photo
    $num = 1;
    foreach ( $_FILES[ "img" ][ "error" ] as $key => $error )
    {
        if ( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) 
        {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES[ "img" ][ "tmp_name" ][ $key ];
            $name = $_FILES[ "img" ][ "name" ][ $key ];
            move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, "$target/$name" );

            $putData = "UPDATE photos_occasion SET image_" . $num . " = '$target/$name' WHERE id = " . $photoOccasionID;
            $result = $db->query( $putData );
            $num++;
        }
    }

    echo "Your event has been add successfully";
}
?>
```

Think this should put you on the way ...

but anyway, as a side note, i think the right way to design your database is like:

table occasion ( id, title, description )

table photos_occasion ( id, occasion_id, image, order )
    here, occasion_id is a foreign key to occasion table ( id column )
    order, is photo number (if you really need to know its order)

Comment: I really love Stack Overflow and the people

Comment: still doesn't understand the last part how to put the "sql insert query ( $putData and $result and if-else )" in my loop can you please help me with this

Comment: OK I got you Mr.Diogo I solved problem 1 but for two I need to know the base just for now and I will make the rest for error uploading and images extension but for now I need to know how to put the names of the uploaded images to my db 
Thanks again Mr.Diogo for helping me with this

Comment: I think I have mistake in my code here look this is my table in my db it look something like this 

 id  title  description  image_1  image_2  image_3  image_4  image_5  image_6  image_7  image_8  image_9  image_10 
  I don't have any "occasion_id" and I will replace my code above please look at it again and tell me?

Comment: this still doesn't answer my question

Comment: this still doesn't answer my question Mr.Diogo you still want me to make another table in my database and save my names in it, what if I want to make it in the same table and please give me example on this "$photoOccasionID = GET_INSERTED_ID_SOMEHOW;" and thanks Mr.Diogo for your assets.

Comment: error_reporting( E_ALL );
include_once( "../config/config.php" );



if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) )
{
 
 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
 
  $photoOccasionID = $_GET['id'];
  
 }

I try to get my id by this but still give me this 

Notice: Undefined variable: photoOccasionID in C:\wamp\www\africa_academy\includes\add_photos_and_occasion.php on line 47

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you Mr.Diogo is the first thing I have to say and this is the final code I have put with some help from my master

```
<?php 

        error_reporting( E_ALL );
        include_once( "../config/config.php");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Add event</title>
<link href="../css_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

    <?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $target = 'upload_occasion/';

    $title = $_POST[ 'img_title' ];
    $des = $_POST[ 'img_des' ];

    // insert occasion info
    $putData = "INSERT INTO photos_occasion ( id, title, description ) values ( '', '$title', '$des' )";
    $result = $db->query( $putData ) or die ( $db->error );
    $photoOccasionID=$db->insert_id;
    // NOTICE THIS LINE .. you should implement something to get the inserted id (maybe from the $result)


    // then update occasion with each photo
    $num = 1;
    foreach ( $_FILES[ "img" ][ "error" ] as $key => $error )
    {
        if ( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) 
        {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES[ "img" ][ "tmp_name" ][ $key ];
            $name = $_FILES[ "img" ][ "name" ][ $key ];
            move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, "$target/$name" );

            $putData = "UPDATE photos_occasion SET image_" . $num . " = '$target/$name' WHERE id = " . $photoOccasionID;
            $result = $db->query( $putData );
            $num++;



        }

    }

    echo "Your event has been add successfully";
}
?>




<body>
<div id="werpper">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="header">My control - Panel</div>
                <div id="body_cntent">
                    <div id="left_side">
                      <p>Home and instructions</p>
                          <p><a href="../control_panel.php">main directory events</a>                      </p>
                      <p><a href="add_event.php">Add new event</a>                      </p>
                      <p><a href="add_photos_and_occasion.php"></a><a href="add_photos_and_occasion.php">Add Photos_occasion</a></p>
                    </div>
                            <div id="right_side">

                                <h1>Add  Photos and occasion</h1>
                             <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                               <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="10">
                                 <tr>
                                   <td>Images tiltle</td>
                                   <td><input name="img_title" type="text" value="" size="50" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td>Images Description</td>
                                   <td><textarea name="img_des" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td>Images (max 10 img)</td>
                                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img1">Image 1</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img2">Image 2</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField2" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img3">Image 3</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField3" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img4">Image 4</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField4" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img5">Image 5</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField5" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img6">Image 6</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField6" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img7">Image 7</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField7" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img8">Image 8</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField8" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img9">Image 9</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField9" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td><label for="img10">Image 10</label></td>
                                   <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="fileField10" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                   <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
                                     &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                   <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Empty fields" /></td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>
                             </form>
                        </div>
                </div>
             <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code I have put it here to help others to across this problem I sat for 5 days trying to solve.

this code allow users to put brows the images they want and also put they names in the database so they can call it to any where they want

Thanks again Mr.Diogo and have a good night.